# Why is it called Mixolydian #11 and not Mixolydian #4?

Tags: theory, terminology, modes

I was watching an [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2y2_xh-bF0) and the guy's talking about Mixolydian #11 being one of the modes of the melodic minor.

The regular G mixolydian looks like:
G A B C D E F G

And the G Mixolydian #11 looks like:
G A B C# D E F G

So why is it called #11 and not #4 since we sharped the 4th degree? Also, at what point do you call a mode a dominant. I recall when the 3rd scale degree of Phrygian is sharped, they call it the Phrygian Dominant.

Comment: I've heard it called both. The #11 emphasizes the chord-aspect, but I suspect that most people don't give too much thought to which way they name the scale. Note that Mixolydian #11 (I usually call it Lydian Dominant) is a mode of the Melodic Minor scale, not Harmonic Minor, though.

Comment: He also calls it 'b5', which is possibly worse - as you've now lost the C note (in key G Mix.) and have two Ds! I see no good reason for using 11 at all. The 4th note is affected as well.

Comment: @DavidBowling - good catch with melodic rather than harmonic. That 6th note is key.

Comment: You can derive the same mode by lowering the seventh degree of the Lydian scale, so you might also call it Lydian flat 7 (or flat 14?).  But it might make more sense just to pick another Greek place and name it after that.

Comment: I think I remember seeing once, perhaps in Levine's The Jazz Theory Book, that the difference comes in either chord quality or function, as in major chords it's #11, minor chords it's #4 *OR* dominant chords it's #11 and tonic chords it's #4 (these are meant as illustrative examples and not meant to indicate the actual rules/conventions for chord nomenclature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, I've always heard **scales referred to with their scale degrees altered, not chord extensions**. Therefore, it's Mixolydian ♯4 in my book (or at least in my answer).

**"Dominant" as part of a scale name (or any name) always means that the third is major and the seventh is minor.** Usually, when it's something like "(mode name) Dominant", it means that it's just that mode but with the necessary alterations to make it a dominant scale. So, Phrygian Dominant is like Phrygian but with a major third, since it already has the minor seventh. Mixolydian Dominant doesn't exist, for obvious reasons. A lot of the modes don't really have a "dominant" version; Dorian Dominant would just be Mixolydian.

Phrygian Dominant and Lydian Dominant are the only two scales I've heard named using this convention, although I suppose one could have a Locrian Dominant scale.

***TL;DR: Scales take scale-degree alterations, and Dominant in the name means M3 and m7.***

Answer (score 3):

I have heard it called "Mixolydian #4" or "Lydian Dominant."

Maybe I have seen "Mixolydian #11" but I probably ignored that as an obvious mistake and understood it to mean `#4` in the scale.

`#4` makes sense in a scale description. `#11` makes sense in a chord description.

Answer (score 1):

Both names are used and both make sense. You're right that it's the fourth scale degree that is sharpened, but as a tension, that scale degree is usually added to harmonies in the higher octaves, hence #11.

As for your question on the name "dominant" in phrygian dominant, it's about the major third. Phrygian has a minor third, and its basic seventh chord (made of the 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th scale degrees) is a minor seventh chord. If you change the third to a major third you get phrygian dominant, which has a dominant seventh chord as its basic seventh chord. That's also how this scale is used very often: over a dominant chord in minor. E.g., over A7(b9) resolving to Dm (6,7) you can play A phrygian dominant (which is just the fifth mode of D harmonic minor). Unlike the phrygian mode, phrygian dominant has the leading tone resolving to the tonic. E.g., in the key of the D minor, A phrygian dominant has a C# which resolves to the tonic D.

Any scale with scale degrees 1, 3, 5, and 7 that form a dominant seventh chord can be considered a "dominant" scale, e.g., mixolydian, mixolydian #11, phrygian dominant. Of course, there are also other scales that can be used over dominant chords, such as the half-whole (8-tone) scale, or the altered scale (seventh mode of melodic minor).